# issue with Joomla and CiviCRM Dashboard as a Menu Item

Tags: joomla, menu, dashboard

I'm following the directions found here:

http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/website-integration/integrating-with-joomla/

I'm having no problem adding some of the other CiviCRM menu item types to a menu, but when I try to add CiviCRM Dashboard to a menu item then navigate to the page using the navigation on the front end, I receive the following error message:

"0
SORRY BUT WE ARE NOT ABLE TO PROVIDE THIS AT THE MOMENT.
COULD NOT FIND VALID VALUE FOR ID
RETURN TO HOME PAGE.

OH MY GOSH! YOU FOUND IT!!!
Looks like the page you're trying to visit doesn't exist.
Please check the URL and try your luck again.
TAKE ME HOME"

I've gone through the "Advanced, Link Type, Page Display, Metadata, ..." etc options under Menu Manager and I haven't been able to uncover anything obvious.  I also have made sure that access is set at "Registered", and I am logged in as "Registered" on the front end.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

There are actually several dashboards in CiviCRM. The two you may be confusing are

- the "user dashboard" which is visible at http://example.org/index.php/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/user&reset=1
- the main "backend" dashboard at http://example.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/dashboard

Both require the user to be logged in or the page will not work.
Note that the url's are constructed differently, and any page you want available to normal (non super) users should point to /index.php and not /administrator.